# Warning with struct initialization

Tags: c, struct, initialization, warnings

I have this struct:

```
struct ChangeIntItem
{
    char *unit;
    const char **parser;
    int *changevalue;
    uint16_t *change_eeprom_value;
    int maximum;
    int minimum;
};
```

I want to initialize other variables with this struct-Variable:

```
struct ChangeIntItem ChangeIntItemTypeBoolean = { .unit = "", .minimum = 0, .maximum = 1, .parser = {"off", "on"}};
```

It is working fine but I get some warnings:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     braces around scalar initializer    Handsteuerung   C:\Users\...    11

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     (near initialization for 'ChangeIntItemTypeBoolean.parser') Handsteuerung   C:\Users\...    11

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     initialization from incompatible pointer type   Handsteuerung   C:\Users\...    11

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     (near initialization for 'ChangeIntItemTypeBoolean.parser') Handsteuerung   C:\Users\...    11

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     excess elements in scalar initializer   Handsteuerung   C:\Users\...    11

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     (near initialization for 'ChangeIntItemTypeBoolean.parser') Handsteuerung   C:\Users\...    11
```

In another case I wrote a function which sets the variables of the struct to default-values but I prefer this method because its much shorter.

All mistakes where caused by '.parser = {"off", "on"}' but I don't get my mistake...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), so change init to

```
struct ChangeIntItem ChangeIntItemTypeBoolean = { .unit = "", .minimum = 0, .maximum = 1, .parser = (const char *[]){"off", "on"}};
```

Test

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct ChangeIntItem
{
    char *unit;
    const char **parser;
    int *changevalue;
    uint16_t *change_eeprom_value;
    int maximum;
    int minimum;
};

int main()
{
    struct ChangeIntItem ChangeIntItemTypeBoolean = { .unit = "", .minimum = 0, .maximum = 1, .parser = (const char *[]){"off", "on"}};

    printf ("%s - %s\n", ChangeIntItemTypeBoolean.parser[0], ChangeIntItemTypeBoolean.parser[1]);
}
```

Output

```
off - on
```

Comment: Alternatively, `parser` could be a flexible array member of type `const char* parser[]`. There are very few cases where pointer-to-pointer variable declarations make sense.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, with VLA `parser` should be last member of struct, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes its easier than you think ;)

Answer (score 4):

Member `parser` is a pointer.

Change it to an array of pointers, so the initialization can be kept the same:

```
 const char *parser[2];
```

Or use a compound literal or another variable:

```
.parser = ( const char*[]){"off", "on"}

const char* array[2] = {"off", "on"};
.parser = array
```

Comment: @LPs No, it is a pointer. Phrase *pointer of pointers* doesn't have any meaning.